# Google Sheets Script - Hard Copy Duplicate Sheet and rename

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- I want to duplicate a sheet but values only, not the formula
- I then want the duplicated sheet to be renamed with that days date + original sheet name
- I want this to happen every day at 11pm

I am very new to scripts - I have tried adapting other answers to questions here with no success

Comment: Share what you have tried, pointing where you got stuck. :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function dupeSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:ss");//date string
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter((sh => {
    if(!~sh.getName().indexOf('---')) {
      return true;//returns sheets that don't have ---
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })).filter(e => e).forEach(sh => {
    let vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    let ns = ss.insertSheet(`${sh.getName()} --- ${dts}` );//create new sheet
    ns.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);//add sheet data to new sheet
  });
}
```